# Full Calendar Rails with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, calendar

I am struggling with the Fullcalendar as I do not have much experience on jquery.

I have a event model, with `column names`; `price:float`, `availability:string`, `start_date:datetime`, `end_date:datetime`.

After user sign up, they fill a form of availability and price. So, what I would like to do is, when User goes to a specific page (lets say index.html.erb of Event), the calendar will full fill  every dates with the price. And past days can not be clicked. Here is an image what I would like to see;

[image]

On the calendar, if user clicks on a date popup shows up and he/she can update the date(s), Here is the image;

[image]

But there must be only 1 price on a calendar. Whether user selects a day or a date range, it should update those days, not adding a new line. Here is another img;

[image]

So, I thought to do that with validates uniqueness in Rails but then T thought it would give an error. I tried with putting a button outside of a calendar and when user clicks on a date popup form opens but it works for `#create` action. If I try something like;

```
<%= form_for @event, :url => url_for(:controller => 'events', :action => 'update') do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :availability %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :availability %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :end_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when I use `#update` it throws an error.
So far, this is jquery, almost empty;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here

          eventSources: [

                // your event source
                {
                    url: 'events.json', // use the `url` property
                    color: 'yellow',    // an option!
                    textColor: 'black'  // an option!
                }

                // any other sources...

            ]

    })

});
</script>
```

And I found this to make past dates unselectable but could not put inside of jquery.(I am that much unexperienced)

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if(check < today)
    {
        // Previous Day. show message if you want otherwise do nothing.
                // So it will be unselectable
    }
    else
    {
        // Its a right date
                // Do something
    }
  },
```

Comment: The picture looks a bit incomplete, but in your json code, you're not passing price, so you're not going to get price. There isn't enough context of what you want to do and where you're at with your code. Can you re-structure the question to address a specific question?

Comment: I've added some questions directly in edits for you to answer. Not sure if I'll be able to help you tomorrow, but it'll help clarify the question to others that can

Comment: Thank you I have updated the question as you suggested. May be there is another way to do it. But that is what I thought. Thank you for your time. Hope you ll have time to help me